# Click not detected by dynamicly added jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks for your attention.

I have a DOM in which one I dynamicly insert a JS script element using :

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.id = "dynJS";
script.type = "type/javascript";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Some events later, I generate buttons in the page. Then, I add the following code in this script element to listen the click on these buttons :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "button#but1", function(){
        alert("click A");
    }
}
```

(respectively for the other buttons)

But the click isn't detected. Does anyone know why ?

**EDIT : Problem solved.**

Thanks to the comments, I fix the issue moving the delegated click listener in a code pre-existing the buttons add, avoiding the redundant script add.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I am not sure if the script will execute that way.

Comment: Can you provide an example using the snippet button ?

Comment: Is the JS code in your second example in the script element you append? Seems a little redundant to append the entire script when you can just use a delegated event handler - as you already are - in the DOM when the page originally loads.

Comment: Is there some error seen in developer console?

Comment: @j08691 Can you please let me know a better dupe?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan You're right, it is redundant. So I'm gonna try to move the delegated event handler to the static script already in at the buttons loading.

Comment: @Avezan Nothing shows up.

Comment: You might be better off with a vanilla js event delegation handler. Bind the click to the body and then check to see if the event target is the one you care about. https://gomakethings.com/checking-event-target-selectors-with-event-bubbling-in-vanilla-javascript/  I'm not sure that jquery is handling that in the same way and might be attaching to the DOM elements at the time of invocation. Could be wrong though..